# How to run one thread group at a time in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have 3 different Thread groups i.e **CreateClient**, **GetClient** and **"ListClient"** but when I start running the test then all these thread group run one by one. If I only want to run thread group **"Get Client"** then how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can select the `Thread Group` that you want to execute using `Validate` option.

`Right click` on selected Thread Group (`Get Client`), click on `Validate`. JMeter runs only `Get Client` Thread Group.

From JMeter [3.0 change log](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) (refer `New and Noteworthy` section):

> New validation feature, in one click run a selection of Thread Groups
>   with 1 user, no pause and 1 iteration

Answer (score 10):

You can disable(Right click on thread group) the thread group which you don't want to execute.